Theorem 12.14 in Jech's Set Theory
I'm struggling to understand a few things regarding Theorem 12.14 (picture at the end) in Jech's Set Theory:
First of all, does $(12.22)$ mean
$$\Big[\forall x_1\in M\ldots\forall x_n\in M \phi^M(x_1,\ldots,x_n)\Big] \iff \Big[\forall x_1\ldots\forall x_n\phi(x_1,\ldots,x_n)\Big]?$$
Secondly, if $|M|\le |M_0|\cdot \aleph_0 = \max\{|M_0|,\aleph_0\}$, then how can we guarantee $|M|$ is countable? In particular, what if $M_0$ is uncountable?
Thirdly, what does it mean to say "$\sigma$ is a true sentence" in Remark 3? Do they mean that if $M_0$ is a model of ZFC for which $\phi$ is true, then $M$ is a model of ZFC$\cup\{\phi\}$?


True, as in it holds in the universe (the one you're working with).
